# Twiiter on iPhone iOS 4.3.3

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I am trying to access the twitter from my iOS app and i am getting this error.
I have searched on the net for that but could not get a solution 
Can Anyone help ?

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x81e7c20 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token, NSUnderlyingError=0x81c5900 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"}``
```

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

Get [Sharkit](http://getsharekit.com/) from link and use that in the application